# MongoDB Conditional Projection based on existence of query of subdocument in Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a schema in which properties can have respective "override" documents stored in an Array("overrides")

E.g.

```
{
    foo:'original foo',
    overrides: [
        {property:'foo', value:'foo override'},
        {property:'bar', value:'bar override'},
    ]
}
```

I want to project a field for the override value if it exists, otherwise, the original property.

So something like this

```
project: { overrideOrOriginal: {$cond: fooOverrideExists ? fooOverrideValue : originalFooValue }
```

So in this example, I would expect `overrideOrOriginal` to equal `'foo override'` . If -  `{property:'foo', value:'foo override'}` subDoc didn't exist in the `overrides` array (or if `overrides` array itself didn't even exist)...then I'd expect overrideOrOriginal = 'original foo'

How can I do this?
I was thinking I'd need `$exists` in tandem with `$cond`. But the complication here is that I'm searching for a subDoc in an Array based on a query

Thanks!

Comment: if you give the expected output, it would help alot

Comment: if you can explain to us, all your documents have this "foo" field? or each document can have another name for "foo"? and you want to do this in all documents or for a specific "foo" value? Add 2-3 documents, and post the expected output, else we are sending answers assuming things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$ifNull` to check if field is null then return empty array
- `$in` to check "foo" is in `overrides.property` array
- `$indexOfArray` to get index of array element in `overrides.property` array
- `$arrayElemAt` to get element by specific index return from above operator

```
let fooOverrideExists = "foo";
db.collection.find({},
{
  overrideOrOriginal: {
    $cond: [
      { 
        $in: [
          fooOverrideExists, 
          { $ifNull: ["$overrides.property", []] }
        ] 
      },
      {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$overrides.value",
          { $indexOfArray: ["$overrides.property", fooOverrideExists] }
        ]
      },
      "$foo"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SBO4_MC7AgC)

Comment: This should work but I need to account for if `$overrides.property` doesn't exist. I've tried using `$and` in conjunction with your `$in` but keep getting syntax errors. Looks like I need to use compound expression inside `$cond`, but that keeps failing too. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not getting you exactly, can you post an example of this case in your question.

Comment: Please comment out `$overrides` in your playground and you'll see the `$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing` error. Accounting for if this array exists should fix that. So, if it doesn't exist I'd like `$cond` to fail and just return "$foo".

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: this works for a specific "foo" and only if all documents in all the collection have only "foo" as fields check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k6zKFMcH7Re)  question needed more clear explanation i think

Comment: Any idea how I could get this to work on a collection that comes from a `$lookup` stage?

So my main aggregate is gonna be run on a `Parent` collection and is being joined to `Child`...

Then - in `$project` I'd have `Child:{childField1:1, overrideOrOriginal:"your answer" }`

I tried ^, but it keeps thinking there's no overrides at all. I'm guessing there's now a complication with `$overrides.property` and scope of referring to `Child` collection in the projection now.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- find the property , key-value(kv) (it works for all property names)
  (assumes your schema with only string value the value of that   property)
- checks if that it exists in the overrides array
- if it exists, takes the value from the array
- else keeps the original

*checks also cases where override doesnt exists, or its empty array, or property doesn't exist

*in case you want to do it only for a specific "foo" ignore the big first `$set` and use [this code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RTHkIjjJBPc)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9yOwRkJH03r)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "kv": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
              },
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$$this.v"
                  },
                  "string"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "index": {
        "$indexOfArray": [
          "$overrides.property",
          "$kv.k"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "overrideOrOriginal": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$index",
                  -1
                ]
              },
              {
                "$not": [
                  "$overrides"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "$kv.v",
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$overrides.value",
              "$index"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```